# C# Directory copying returns no error, but does not copy directory

Tags: c#, directory, copy, system

I'm writing a very small app to copy a directory from one place to the other with some added automation. The entire application works flawlessly with exception of the actual copy method. The worst part is I'm getting no errors at all, and as most of you know, that's quite worse than getting errors.

Here is the method in question:

```
public static bool CopyDir(string sPath, string dPath)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sPath);
            try
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(file);

                    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sPath, "*",
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sPath, dPath));

                    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sPath, "*.*",
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sPath, dPath), true);
                }
            } catch // this is no use because the Exception is empty.
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false; //the app keeps executing to here and I don't know why
        }
```

Variable dump from debugger:

- sPath: `"C:\\Users\\Jacob Jewett\\Downloads\\func1"`
- dPath: `"C:\\Users\\Jacob Jewett\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\saves\\data\\functions\\"`
- files: [0] `"C:\\Users\\Jacob Jewett\\Downloads\\func1\\main.mcfunction"`

Folder tree of `Downloads\func1` (sPath):

```
func1
  main.mcfunction
```

**EDIT** (2:33PM): OK so here's my refactored code, it returns `File in use` error but does not copy anything.

```
   public static bool CopyDir(string sPath, string dPath)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sPath, "*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sPath, dPath));

                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(dPath, "*.*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sPath, dPath), true);
                return true;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Attempt to copy failed. Raw: "+e,"IO Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT** (8-29-17 12:09PM): I've done some tweaking to the method and I'm at a point where I now get a `Access to path [path] is Denied.`, which is better than nothing but I haven't come across a working solution yet. I did some browsing on here for the error and most say to put `File.SetAttributes()` before the `File.Copy()` method is called. This has no effect. Alternatively, I tried setting the attribute `Read-Only` directory of the `sPath1` to none before any copying is done, and this also has no effect.

Current code:

```
public static bool CopyDir(string sPath, string dPath)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo spdi = new DirectoryInfo(sPath);
        spdi.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sPath, "*",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);

        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(dPath, "*.*",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        { 
            File.SetAttributes(dPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Copy(sPath, newPath);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dPath);
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Attempt to copy failed. (UAC) Raw: "+e,"IO Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very likely hitting the `return false` within the `catch` block. You're hitting an exception, but it's just swallowed and you never see the error.

Comment: I did try adding a better catch block, and the exceptions returns nothing. It's not even going to the catch block from what I can see.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: Haven't really touched the debugger other than for breakpoints, how would and what would I want to debug?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `return false` in the catch block.

Comment: Ok, so this is new. I put a break point on the `return false;` thats *not* in the catch (because it wasn't tripped at all), and the paths `sPath` and `dPath` are correct other than having double backslashes. `files` contains the only file in the folder, so thats correct, but it's still not actually doing anything.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the destination folder?   This codes replicated one of my folder structures perfectly, other than (as per my answer below)  always returning false because there is no return true at the end of the try.   Perhaps you meant the very end return false to be true?

Comment: Theoretically, shouldn't File.Copy throw UnauthorizedAccessException if there is a permissions issue?

It also copies correctly using your refactored code on my end... 
What is the folder structure in the source directory you are trying to copy?

Comment: Ok, so I just made the `catch` look for exactly that exception, and none is caught, instead it returns true. (Using my latest revision of code with the addition of `catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)`)

Comment: I've tested on my end with your refactored code and the exact folder structure (changing the user for mine, obv). It copied the file to the correct directory.
Couple things we could check: Could you put a breakpoint on the File.Copy line, to see if it gets skipped over for some reason? Also how are you validating that the file gets copied over? (seems like a dumb question, but better to get those out of the way, lol)

Comment: Ok slapped at breakpoint on the `File.Copy()` - its being executed but i realized that newPath was for some reason pointing to the downloads not the dest. so I changed `Directory.GetFiles()` to dPath. Now we are getting some where. It gives a file in use error, which is better than none, but how do I fix this because they're are no other applications using the file and it's still not copying the files.

Comment: Shouldn't newPath be pointing to the downloads though?
File.Copy takes sourcePath, destPath and shouldOverwrite as arguments, therefore your sourcePath should be "C:\\Users\\Jacob Jewett\\Downloads\\func1\\main.mcfunction" and destPath "C:\\Users\\Jacob Jewett\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\saves\\data\\functions\\main.mcfunction". Basically now you are trying to copy the open file onto itself, which would explain the file in use error :)

Comment: I took these for loops from another code file, thus why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I reread your code and I think I've got the real issue.

The instructions below are quite sufficient to copy all subdirectories and files to the destination.

```
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sPath, "*",
         SearchOption.AllDirectories))
         Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sPath, dPath));

foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sPath, "*.*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sPath, dPath), true);
```

The outer foreach is redundant.

Here is corrected code:

```
public static bool CopyDir(string sPath, string dPath)
{
    try
    {
         foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sPath, "*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sPath, dPath));

         foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sPath, "*.*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sPath, dPath), true);
    }
    catch // this is no use because the Exception is empty.
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false; //the app keeps executing to here and I don't know why
}
```

That said, it is a good practice to do something with the Exception in the catch block. Even if it's just logging it :) That way you can rule it out if it's not logging.

Comment: the `string[] files` is not empty though. The debugger shows that it contains all the correct files in the source directory, `main.mcfunction`.

Comment: right, my bad :S Edited my answer to remove that assumption. The code still works on my end however, so it must be something else.

What does the folder structure look like for sPath?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are getting no errors, do the files copy? If so then maybe you are simply forgetting to return true at the end of the outer foreach loop in the try block.

Otherwise this code replicated a folder structure perfectly for me.

```
try{
    foreach(...)
    {
       // etc
    }

    return true;     // <<<<<<--------
}
catch
{
}
return false;
```

Also, if you are running this in the main GUI thread then it's going to lock things up and the debugger will likely complain about a context switch dead lock, so make sure you're running it in a thread.

In terms of using the debugger, put a break point where you want to stop then use F10 to step over a line and F11 to step into a line.